# Why 1:M and not N:M (ER diagram)

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I found this from here  https://www.tutorialcup.com/dbms/object-based-data-models.htm

[image]

and I try to understand why the type of mapping between Student and Lecturer is 1 to many. So, I have a question...

Why the mapping is 1:M and not N:M? As the diagram represented, I can understand that one student can be tough by many teachers but one teacher can teach at most one student

Comment: This seems like homework.

Comment: I student would have many teachers and a teacher would have many students. The ERD looks good to me.

Comment: One teacher has many student in their class.

Comment: Now , can you undersrand which is my problem??

Comment: I guess no. Sorry.

Comment: In my experience, lecturers teach many students, not just one. Also, lecturers can teach multiple subjects, subjects can be taught by multiple lecturers, and subjects can have multiple classes. But that would make every relationship in the diagram M:N. Maybe the author wanted an example that demonstrated 1:N and 1:1 relationships as well (but then why not a ternary or higher relationship too?) and just modified an existing diagram rather than think up a different example.

Comment: Also, the tutorials on that site are confused and misleading. I suggest you look into [object-role modeling](http://orm.net/) instead.

Comment: Nice ! So, the erd is not correct? Could we say this, or is  a hypothesis that the author made?

Comment: briskovich . The diagram doesn't show what you say.

Comment: You need *@user* for a comment notification to go to a commenter who is not the poster and not the only commenter.

Comment: @briskovich There's nothing wrong with homework questions per se. Also since the ERD has M:1, "[1] student would have many teachers and a teacher would have many students" contradicts "The ERD looks good", and your second comment doesn't agree with the ERD either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this model could represent private tutorship.

One student has many tutors who are paid to exclusively teach the student - there's the 1:M

Each tutor specialises in 1 subject - that's the 1:1

Each tutor takes a few classes a week - that's the 1:M

A class could be taught by more than 1 tutor, perhaps physics and maths combined to explain a particular topic - that's the 1:M

There's nothing wrong with the diagram, it simply represents something you are not used to. Obviously my interpretation is just that, an interpretation, but I wanted to demonstrate that the diagram isn't necessarily incorrect because it doesn't fit what you imagined.

Comment: Ok !! So, somebody can tell that a diagram is correct if and only if he can create a "story" that is real...

Comment: It depends on what the diagram represents. I just gave an example where it could be correct. You'd have to ask the diagram designer what it represents to know for sure. My point was that a diagram isn't necessarily incorrect if you don't know what it represents.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a system unless you have been told what every entity & relationship *is* in business/application/domain terms. If you don't know then you need to ask. Cardinality is just one property of a relationship. (As are attributes & particiant entities.) One that you do not even need to know in order to update or query. (It is relevant to enforcing integrity.)

Judging by the names of entities & relationships, using common sense, ie *guessing*, because the diagram doesn't say, lecturer-Teaches-student would be M:N. But also by common sense it is redundant because we would expect that the lecturers teaching a student would be derivable from the lecturers teaching the subjects of the classes the student attends.

The diagram is peculiar in having two diamonds with the same name 'Teaches'. (Although they are distinguishable by having different pairs of participating entities.) If we took lecturer-Teaches-student to mean Tutors then the diagram M:1 would make more sense. There are two conventions for labeling cardinalities, look-here & look-across. In look-here, a number at an entity type tells you how many times an instance can participate in the relationship. Here that is consistent with the diagram cardinality: a student participates once, so has one tutor, and a lecturer would tutor many students. In look-across, a number by an entity type tells you how many times a subtuple of instances of the other entity types can participate in a relationship.

Also, the 1:1 cardinality for lecturer-Teaches-subject is unusual but possible. And who knows what lecturer-Takes-class means. Maybe it means Lectures, and gives the classes Lecturers lecture, which presumably only Have subjects that the lecturer Teaches. Also the foreign _ID attributes of entities don't belong under normal expectations for this application & style of diagram.

That web site is poorly written, forget about it. There are literally dozens of published academic textbooks free online, plus slides, plus courses. Also, you need to follow the style(s) of your class's reference(s).

Never draw a diagram without including a key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !! I just try to understand ER diagrams and the advices that you gave me are very good !